# autoplay sound in cellphone

Tags: android, html, iphone

I uploaded a sound to my website as an audio tag, it works well at PC but in android and iPhone the auto-play doesn't work. I think it depends on the cellphone browser because I changed my android browser and it worked. Is there any other solution how to make it work anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var audio = new Audio("songs/test.mp3");
audio.play();
```

It works on default android browser

Comment: any way to control it from javascript?

Comment: var audio = document.getElementById("player");

Comment: Where should I write this code? in javascript? `var audio = new Audio("songs/test.mp3");`

Comment: it's strange because i used this code var audio= null;
$(document).ready(function(){
 var audio = new Audio("songs/test.mp3");
 audio.play();
 
}); and it worked well